# Get even.target which is under the dragged object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I am using framer-motion to drag items. To identify drag end I am using `onDragEnd` callback with `event.target.closest()`. The expected result is to return an item underneath the dragged object. Unfortunately, it returns the dragged object itself.

I know that it does work however because when I grab an object at its very end (near its bound), I am able to console log a proper object. Any workaround for this?